# ProductService is not initialized in the constructor in Controller

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple ProductController which uses ProductService to retrieve a product given the productId. However, when the productService is initialized it is undefined in the controller method. What is the problem? Why isn't the service initialized?

Here is the code

```js
    export class ProductsController {
  
          productsService:ProductService;
 
          constructor() {
            console.log('Entered constructor ProductsController')
            // This is always undefined in retrieveProducts()
            this.productsService = new ProductService() 
          }
   
         async  retrieveProducts(request:Request, response:Response, next:NextFunction){
          try {
             // This works if I do this instead 
             const productService = new ProductService()  
             const productId = request.params.productId
             const product = await this. productsService.findById(productId)
             if(product){
              response.status(200).json(product)
              return 
            }
            response.status(400).json({message: 'No Products could be found'})
            return 
 
 
           } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error occurred during processing request', error)
              response.status(400).json({message: 'Error occurred during processing'})
           } 
     
    }
  }
```

Here is the error indicating that the productService is not initialized

Error occurred during processing request TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
(reading 'productService')
at findById

Comment: `this` context is not correct. In `findById` let's try `productsController. retrieveProducts.bind(productsController)` instead.

Comment: I don't understand what it is you are suggesting. The method is findById is in ProductService. What does productsController.retrieveProducts.bind(productsController) mean.  I don't create any instance of productsController. Can show code that explains what you mean?

Comment: Are you importing `ProductService` into your `ProductsController` class file?

Comment: Yes I am importing it. i.e.   import {ProductService} from ''../service/product-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be related to the scoping of the 'this' keyword. In your retrieveProducts method, when you use this.productsService, it's not referring to the instance of ProductsController. In JavaScript, the value of the 'this' keyword is determined by how a function is called. When you have a method in a class, and you call that method without preserving the context, the 'this' keyword might not refer to the instance of the class. 
You can either bind the function to the instance of the class in the constructor using the bind method. Something like this,

```js
export class ProductsController {

    productsService: ProductService;

    constructor() {
        this.productsService = new ProductService();

        // Bind the retrieveProducts method to the instance of the class
        this.retrieveProducts = this.retrieveProducts.bind(this);
    }

    async retrieveProducts(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
       // ...method implementation 
    }
}
```

Or you can use an arrow function for your retrieveProducts method, which ensures that 'this' retains its context from the class instance.

```js
export class ProductsController {

    productsService: ProductService;

    constructor() {
        this.productsService = new ProductService();
    }

    // Use arrow function to retain 'this' context
    retrieveProducts = async (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        // ...method implementation 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much really grateful.  What surprises me is that I have initialized object instances of classes in the exact same way and it just works.